# Iterate array inside html

Tags: html, jquery, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am developing a product sale page. I have used a jquery plugin for implementing a carousel image.

Thats the library:

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Carousel-Plugin-jQuery-RV-Gallery/

I am using the image statically for testing, with some images from internet. But I have to store the images dynamically, so amb I trying to iterate an ARRAY inside html. That array is html formatted.

I need to replace the shopify links, for the content of the arrayImagesProduct. Each product, it may have one, two, three,.. images. So I need to iterate the array .

I have tried this:

```
$("#productImages").html(arrayImagesProduct.join(''));
```

but then the slider it doesnt work. I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined
    at Gallery.countMoveRight (RV-gallery.js:121)
    at RV-gallery.js:36
    at dispatch (VM1025 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at elemData.handle (VM1025 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
```

```
function showProduct(productCode){
    var arrayImagesProduct = [];
    $.post('../ServletJson', {
        elem : 'productInfo',
        code: productCode,
    }, function(data) {
        $.each(data,function(t,elem){
            /* some stuff */


            arrayImagesProduct.push('<img class="gallery-item" src="../loadImgProduct.jsp?idImg='+elem.idImg+'&code=productCode">');

            
        });
            $("#productImages").html(arrayImagesProduct.join(''));
    });
}
```

How I can iterate the arrayImagesProduct array inside the html?

Inside here

```
<div class="gallery" id="productImages">

<!-- iterate arrayImagesProduct -->

<\div>
```

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row image-gallery-container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
            <div class="gallery" id="productImages">
                <img class="gallery-item" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0122/2724/8185/products/0719_2019_Top1_b_ae870642-af0d-4655-811d-d597ed2a8bcc_720x.jpg?v=1574239406">
                <img class="gallery-item" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0122/2724/8185/products/0719_2019_Top1_a_720x.jpg?v=1574239409">
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- more content -->
</div>

</body>
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined
    at Gallery.countMoveRight (RV-gallery.js:121)
    at RV-gallery.js:36
    at dispatch (VM1025 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at elemData.handle (VM1025 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
```

The carousel is instantiating doing the declaration:

```
 <div class="gallery">
```

```
jQuery('.gallery').eq(0).initGallery({
    nav: ['<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_left</i>', '<i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i>'],
    close: "<i class='material-icons'>close</i>",
    aspectRatio: 3/2,
    showDots: true,
    showNavIfOneItem: false,
    showNav: false,
    arrows: true,
    transition: "slide",
    transitionTime: 700,
});


jQuery.fn.initGallery = function(options) {
      if(!options) {
          options={};
      }
      var galleries=[];
      for (let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
          options.gallery = this.eq(i);
          galleries[i] = new Gallery(options);
      }
 };
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "_but then the slider it doesnt work._". Check your console, does it give an error or _anything_ to help us figure out why it "isn't working"?

Comment: The console doesnt print any error: With that    $("#productImages").html(arrayImagesProduct.join('')); the carousel doesn't appear. The images are shown one under the other

Comment: If the carousel doesn't appear, that indicates there should be an error.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yes I got an error, sorry. Thats it: 
````
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined
    at Gallery.countMoveRight (RV-gallery.js:121)
    at RV-gallery.js:36
    at dispatch (VM1025 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at elemData.handle (VM1025 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)````

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i have edited the question, and added the error

Comment: So what I'm thinking is that `../loadImgProduct.jsp?idImg='+elem.idImg+'&code=productCode` is returning something incorrectly, or that plugin doesn't allow you to load images that way

Comment: Where are you initializing the rv-gallery plugin? Are you doing that _after_ you set the HTML?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I haved added how the rv-gallery plugin is initializating.

Comment: Is that done _after_ you set up all the HTML?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton yes